# NSLocalizedString displays key not value

Tags: iphone, ios

I am implementing localization in my app.

Here is the code,

```
 C_TITLE.text = NSLocalizedString(@"C_TITLE", nil);
```

// strings files

```
 localizable.strings (English)

 "C_TITLE" = "English";

 localizable.strings (French)

 "C_TITLE" = "French";
```

But the label displays text "C_TITLE", which is key not value.

I done localization in my previous app but not faced this issue.

Code is working in simulator but not on device. Please help...

Thanks.

Comment: same issue with me, on simulator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that it's spelled Localizable.strings, not localizable.strings. That would explain why it works on the Simulator and not on the device as the OS X file system is not case sensitive but the iPhone's is.

Comment: I had this same problem once and it took a couple days for me to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

use [C_TITLE setText:NSLocalizedString(@"key",nil)]; 
will solve this.

Comment: [C_TITLE setText:] and C_TITLE.text are the same thing, just different notations.

Comment: actually even the plist file is named Localizable.strings, this issue can happen.:)